# How to match a variable number of rows (based on a different column) to another variable number of rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently all of my data is in an Excel file, but I'm not sure if Excel is the best or easiest place to do this. I kind of know some VBA stuff, but I'm definitely still a newbie at it, so help is greatly appreciated! I'm also open to suggestions using other programs (R, Python, etc.) if someone knows better than I do.

Here is an example of a short version of what my data could look like.

| IPIndex | IPLabel | Trial | CurrentFixIndex | CurrentFixX | CurrentFixY | IP2Match | CountMatches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | 1 | 1 | 550 | 150 | 1,4 | 2 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | 1 | 2 | 600 | 300 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | 1 | 3 | 400 | 400 |  |  |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | 1 | 1 | 500 | 200 |  |  |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | 1 | 2 | 650 | 350 |  |  |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | 1 | 3 | 250 | 700 |  |  |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | 1 | 4 | 450 | 150 |  |  |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | 2 | 1 | 250 | 600 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1st 3 Seconds | 2 | 2 | 600 | 400 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | 2 | 1 | 300 | 650 |  |  |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | 2 | 2 | 550 | 350 |  |  |
| 2 | 2nd 3 Seconds | 2 | 3 | 350 | 550 |  |  |

The first 6 columns would be the data output and the last 2 columns I need to calculate.

The column *IP2Match* needs to list the value of *CurrentFixIndex* for each *Trial* that "matches" the *CurrentFixX* and *CurrentFixY* values. I need to measure the Euclidean distance between points in *IPIndex* 1 and *IPIndex* 2 within each trial (here I've given an example with 2 trials).

In this case, if the Euclidean distance is 100 or less, that point (*CurrentFixX* and *CurrentFixY*) in *IPIndex* 2 matches the point in *IPIndex* 1.

I need to compare each point (*CurrentFixX* and *CurrentFixY*) in *IPIndex* 2 to each point (*CurrentFixX* and *CurrentFixY*) in *IPIndex* 1 for each trial.

The last column just counts how many points match based on the previous column.

For the first row, the cells *CurrentFixIndex* 1 & 4 (from *IPIndex* 2) match (d <= 100) the *CurrentFixIndex* 1 from *IPIndex* 1 within *Trial* 1.

If it helps, Euclidean distance is measured by d=√(x2−x1)^2 + (y2−y1)^2

Comment: Please share the expected result for e.g. `id=1` according to the screenshot. Also, where will the result be located? Maybe you should create a simpler sample with fewer occurrences and use letters as *IP labels* and integers as *Current Fix X* values and instead of *118.2*.

Comment: I need to know how many cells match per trial. In trial 1 (column D), how many of _IP Label_ “2nd 3 Seconds NP" match those of "1st 3 Seconds". The 118.2 is specific and needs to be, as it’s the maximum that the _Current Fix X_ values can vary based on the IP Label per trial. Essentially, each _Current Fix X_ value in _IP Label_ "1st 3 Seconds" can be +/- 118.2. That new range of numbers then needs to be compared to each _Current Fix X_ in _IP Label_ "2nd 3 Seconds NP".

Comment: In the example above, K2=590. The range of possible values would be 471.8-708.2. Any cells in trial 1 with _IP Label_ “2nd 3 Seconds NP” that fall in that range would be a match.

In trial 1 (col D=1), there are 6 cells that match K2 (K11,K12,K13,K14,K18,K21). There are 4 cells that match K3 (K11,K12,K13,K21), etc.

I know this is a weird and super specific instance, but this is unfortunately what I'm stuck with.

Comment: Please put your sample data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) format and the expected output. It helps to reproduce the scenario and your question will get more attraction.